# Get individual values from JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

There is JSON code from URL:

```
{
    "response": {
        "members": [
            {
                "memberid": "123456"
            }
        ]

    }
}
```

**If I use this code to extract individual values​​, does not list me nothing, why?**

```
$json_url = file_get_contents("http://example.com/json");   
$json = json_decode($json_url, true);
echo $json->response->members->memberid;
```

But when I try to write this ...

```
print_r($json['response']);
```

... so'll get this ...

```
Array ( [members] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [memberid] => 123456 ) ) )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because of the json_decode `true` parameter. See the manual, or http://array.include-once.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property `members` is an array not an object. In fact since you are using `json_decode()` with a second argument, all of `$json` is an associative array and not an object at all.

Try:

```
echo $json['response']['members'][0]['memberid'];
```

### See [PHPfiddle demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ypf-ejt)

Comment: I tried `$json->response->members[0]->memberid`, but it still does not work, it does not list anything, not even a error, just blank page.

Answer (score 3):

You decoded the json response as an array, so you'd have to access it like this:

```
$json_url = file_get_contents("http://example.com/json");   
$json = json_decode($json_url, true);
echo $json['response']['members']['memberid'];
```

Or you could decode it as an object: `json_decode($json);` (removing the `true`) allowing you to reference it as an object - `$json->response->member->memberid`

Answer (score 2):

If you want get array value as object you should use this code to convert array to object:

```
$json =json_decode($json_url, true);
$json=(object)$json;
```

Answer (score 1):

As is, you should be able to access that by

```
$json['response']['members'][0]['memberid']
```